# Можно ли через discord.py получить все каналы в конкретной категории, чтобы в дальнейшем их удалить?

Tags: python, discord.py

Как можно получить все каналы в определённой категории?
При удалении категории нужно сделать так, чтобы удалялись и каналы, внутри неё. Как можно подобное реализовать?

Comment: Решил задачу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Для получения каналов](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get%20channels#discord.Client.get_all_channels)

[Для удаления каналов](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=delete%20channel#discord.abc.GuildChannel.delete)